# Spring OAuth2 token invalid token not redirecting to login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Let me set the stage:

I am building a micro service based architecture Edge Server / Auth Server / UI Server (...).

The OAuth2 authorization_code flow is used, with refresh_token.
My ClientDetailsService, AuthorizationCodeServices, TokenStore, ApprovalStore are all in MySQL.

I use a JWT Access Token.

The login works fine, I am able to request the Edge Server root path (localhost:8765) and I am redirected to the login page belonging to the Auth Server (localhost:9999/uaa/login), which once the user entered the correct credentials redirect me to the home page (localhost:8765).

But when my Token expires (expiry set in the database), I do receive an invalid_token 401 response.
However if I enter the path to the login (localhost:8765/login) the token is refreshed and I am redirected to my home page.

How can I handle this 401 response to request a Token Refresh without having to navigate manually to the login page? Am I missing something obvious in my configuration?

Below the security setup.

Auth Server configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerOAuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    ....

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .approvalStore(approvalStore())
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    /**
      * Configure the /check_token endpoint.
      * This end point will be accessible for the resource servers to verify the token validity
      * @param securityConfigurer
      * @throws Exception
      */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer securityConfigurer) throws Exception {
        securityConfigurer
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
    }
}


@Configuration
@Order(-20)
public class AuthorizationServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ....

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Edge Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class EdgeServerApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Configuring Spring security
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.logout()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:on
    }
    ...
}
```

UI Server:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    /**
     * Launching Spring Boot
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); //NOSONAR
    }

    /**
     * Configuring Token converter
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Configuring HTTP Security
     * @param http
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.logout()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

And here is my client_details data configuration:

```
INSERT INTO oauth_client_details
  (client_id, resource_ids, client_secret, scope, authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri, authorities, access_token_validity, refresh_token_validity, additional_information, autoapprove)
VALUES
  ('spa', NULL, 'spasecret', 'read,write', 'authorization_code,refresh_token,password', '', 'ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT', 3600, 7200, NULL, 'true');
```

Comment: look here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-refresh-token-angular-js

Comment: Thanks @bilak for the link but I am using a ResourceServer to serve my static files.